# Force Youtube to Buffer Whole Video on Pause in the Tab -- issuing with solving (MAC/Chrome)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube, buffer, browser-cache

I use a Starlink in Ukraine from my balcony during blackouts.

Unfortunately, it's Obstructed, so I get something around a minute of stable connection with ±170 megabits per second, then something around up to a minute drop, and then it cycled.

YouTube somewhy caches only a small next amount of the video, so it could not be buffered for a comfortable view -- experiencing issues.

[image]

I tried extensions like SmartVideo for YouTube and Youtube Control Center
They couldn't help me to be able to control buffer size as of now with any settings.

I also tried this script, separately and packed it as *.sh,

```bash
#!/bin/sh

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disk-cache-size=524288000 &
```

Still does not buffering further when on pause or on play-only a small near-standing part whatever I try.

Maybe someone has a workaround for this or any other ideas?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to just download the video itself using [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) for instance. You can use it this way: `yt-dlp 'VIDEO_ID'`

Comment: Hi, Benjamin, Many thanks for the reply, interesting tool, I'll definitely play with that. 

Unfortunately, need this to work automatically for each video for daily usage, so that video might be buffered in the near-standing tab on pause and played normally then. 

Need to find how to make it just be buffered further - without being so related to the stable connection :(